# Rails validation skips on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two buttons Save and Submit. If Submit is triggered validation should run else validation should skip. In my controller's create and update methods I defined if conditions like this to ensure that.

create action

```
@applicant = Applicant.new(applicant_params)
build_images
if !params[:submit_button].blank?

  if !@applicant.save
    render 'new'
  else
    redirect_to users_applicants_path, notice: 'Competition application successfully created.'
  end
else
  @applicant.save(:validate => false)
  redirect_to users_applicants_path, notice: 'Competition application successfully created.'
end
```

update action

```
@applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
build_images
@applicant.assign_attributes(applicant_params)
if !params[:submit_button].blank?

  if !@applicant.save
    render 'edit'
  else
    redirect_to users_applicants_path, notice: 'Competition application successfully updated.'
  end
else
  @applicant.save(:validate => false)
  redirect_to users_applicants_path, notice: 'Competition application successfully updated.'
end
```

When I want to Submit form for the first time validation works fine, but when I Save and then try to Submit validation only works for Applicant and Accompaniment model, but not for Photo and Video. Applicant has_one accompaniment and has_many photos and videos. The problem is somewhere in update, but I am not shure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by adding

`validates_associated :children` to model.

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `update` method :-

```
@model_name.attributes = params[:model_name]
@model_name.save false
```

Comment: Thank for the response, but I think you didn't got it well. The skip validation part is working fine in update and create. My problem is that validation doesn't work when it should, when if!params[:submit_button].blank? is true and validate should be done.